# JavaScript. Como comparo 2 objetos?

Tags: javascript, html, api

Estoy trabajando en con una API. Tengo un `setInterval();` cada 60 segundos que se encarga de hacer un llamado a dicha API.

Básicamente lo que necesito hacer es comparar la lista de objetos que recibo en el primer llamado, con el segundo (cada 60 segundos) y así sucesivamente.

Esto necesito hacerlo porque tengo que actualizar los resultados y el tiempo del partido en cuestión.

Para dejarlo mas en claro: Yo hago un llamado a la API una vez. Con ese llamado lo que hago es esto:

```
for (let i = 0; i < api.fixtures.length; i++) {
            let leagueName = api.fixtures[i].league.name;
            if (
                leagueName !== "NB I"
            ) {
                /* Hago un Div por cada partido que se esté jugando y 
                    le hago un Append a la tabla. */
                let appendDiv = document.createElement("div");
                appendDiv.classList.add("match");
                appendDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="liveMatchDiv">
                                        <div class="team">
                                            <img src="${api.fixtures[i].homeTeam.logo}"> 
                                            <br> ${api.fixtures[i].homeTeam.team_name}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="score">
                                            ${api.fixtures[i].goalsHomeTeam}
                                            <span> - </span>
                                            ${api.fixtures[i].goalsAwayTeam}
                                            <p class="elapsedTime">'${api.fixtures[i].elapsed}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="team">
                                            <img src="${api.fixtures[i].awayTeam.logo}"> 
                                            <br> ${api.fixtures[i].awayTeam.team_name}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>`;
```

Ese código hace esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, cuando hago un segundo llamado a la API, lo que necesito es actualizar, en este caso, el '88, por '89 que es el tiempo del partido.
La API ya me devuelve un objeto llamado "elapsed", que es el que uso en

```
<p class="elapsedTime">'${api.fixtures[i].elapsed}</p>
```

**Entonces necesito actualizar ese viejo "elapsed" con el nuevo que me trae la API.**

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Acaso la llamada a la API no te trae el tiempo?. ¿Por qué necesitas comparar?, podrías re-escribir los datos nuevamente, cada 60 segundos no tiene efecto de rendimiento, al menos únicamente en lo que respecta al marcador y a los minutos.

Comment: Exacto, quiero reescribir los datos cada cierto tiempo (60 seg). Como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: Ya con el setInterval haces eso, no creo que tengas que hacer la comparación, solo vuelve a escribir los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Los Objetos en Javascript no son como otros valores primitivos, por lo tanto no es tan fácil compararlos, sin embargo existe la manera de transformarlos en un valor primitivo, un string, una cadena de caracteres para facilitar la comparación.

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

en este caso el orden de aparición de las llaves importa, en donde un objeto

```
{a:'bar',b:'foo'}
```

y un objeto

```
{b:'foo',a:'bar'}
```

no van a ser iguales con esta comparación.

para esto podrías ordenarlos antes

```
JSON.stringify(obj1.sort()) === JSON.stringify(obj2s.sort())
```